# Could I use stored procedure with command builder and datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview, sqlcommandbuilder

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=.;Database=training; 
                                       integrated security =true");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select *  from mangers",con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd );
    da.Fill(ds, "1");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    da.Update(ds, "1");
}
```

I want to know if I can insert/delete/update in `DataGridView` then it happen same to database by using stored procedure ? 
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "happen same"?

Comment: Yes, research SqlDataAdapter on MSDN. There are examples.

Comment: Do some research on SqlDataAdapter and TableAdapters. I haven't used Tableadapters yet, but I know you can save changes in a DataTable to the database.

Comment: i mean i want to call method which us stored procedure to insert/ update/delete  data in database and send cells of gridview as parameteres so not by using commandbulider and da update dataset  ..

Comment: You don't have to use CommandBuilder with DataAdapters, in fact, I would recommend they never be used. You can set your own insert, update, delete, select commands that use stored procedures. So go to MSDN and read about it.